# Node cors catch middleware callback error

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, cors

I have the following code to check the origin header and allow access, using express and the npm cors plugin

```
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin: any, callback: any) {
        if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    }
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Now I wonder if there is way to catch the "new Error" callback?

And send back a 400 http status?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is explained in the Express docs under [Error Handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

> Express comes with a built-in error handler that takes care of any errors that might be encountered in the app. This default error-handling middleware function is added at the end of the middleware function stack.
>
> If you pass an error to `next()` and you do not handle it in a custom error handler, it will be handled by the built-in error handler; the error will be written to the client with the stack trace. The stack trace is not included in the production environment.

The docs don't go into *that* much more detail on the default handler, but after [looking at the source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090/lib/application.js#L162), the default handler is a separate module called [`finalhandler`](https://github.com/pillarjs/finalhandler).

Anyways, to override this handler, refer to the section in the Express docs titled [**Writing error handlers**](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#writing-error-handlers).

It explains:

> Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other middleware functions, except error-handling functions have four arguments instead of three: `(err, req, res, next)`. For example:
>
> ```
> app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
>   console.error(err.stack)
>   res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
> })
> ```
>
> You define error-handling middleware last, after other `app.use()` and routes calls

So in your case, if you wanted to respond with a 400, you might write something like this:

```js
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin: any, callback: any) {
        if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    }
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// This overrides the default error handler, and must be called _last_ on the app
app.use(function customErrorHandler(err, req, res, next) {
   res.status(400).send('Your custom error message here');
});
```

Express also [includes a sample server](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090/examples/error/index.js) in its repo, showing this erorr handling override.

Comment: Perfect thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: what if we put the cors(corsOptions) only on specific route, which we usually put on different folder e.g. /routes/index.js. How to 'throw' it into that error handling in app.js 
 file ?