# Handling CORS errors in Node application

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I use the [cors module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) in a Node application to perform some CORS checks. This is the code:

```
var corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (config.get('CORS').whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            logger.debug("ORIGIN ALLOWED: " + origin);
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            logger.debug("ORIGIN NOT ALLOWED BY CORS: " + origin);
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'),false);
        }
    }
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

It works as expected, but when there's a forbidden request, the error is returned as a full web page, so it's difficult to parse from the frontend. This is an example of a returned error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Not allowed by CORS</h1>
<h2></h2>
<div>Error: Not allowed by CORS
    at origin (/home/user/expapp/app.js:105:13)
    ...etc

</body>
</html>
```

I could parse it in the frontend app, but I'd like to know if there's a way to send a simpler error, like an object with a code and a message.

Thanks!

Comment: Please have a look at it. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428647/node-cors-catch-middleware-callback-error

Comment: As I can see, I didn't use the right words in Google to find this page :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Zain pointed out, this question was already asked (sorry, it seems that I didn't hit the right search in Google).

Cheers,